# How to use react.js with a multi page website (Non SPA)?

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, browserify

I have a laravel app. 
For pages with such routing: `/admin/entity/` i want to use react components with react router to handle `/admin/entity/:id` route.

If i use browserify to bundle all components in one file, i can't access any component to render it from outside since browserify wraps it to closure. Thus, i have few questions:

Should i create separate bundle.js file for each page and render components explicitly in that file?

Or should i precompile each component from jsx to js and render it inline from `*.blade.php` file?

Does it make sense to include react library to bundle.js or i can load it explicitly from view?

Comment: If your bundle has a client-side router in it then it doesn't matter if it's a single bundle (for that reason)

Comment: but if i user client-side router it captures the whole url on every page and tells that route is not found in other pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my *opinions*:

- You should bundle React and all your code in all pages that will have any part rendered by React components (From what I gather, `/admin/entity`).
- Your React component should always be rendered to a specific element (e.g., an empty `<div>`) and should have something like a [React Router](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/) configured so that it ignores `/admin/entity` but renders `/admin/entity/:id`. Your challenge is that any links that point to a different `:id` URL should optimally be inside the React components, using `Link` components. This will hook up your router automatically.

Your routes will probably look like this:

```
<Route path="admin/entity/:id" handler={Entity} />
```

I believe that, when you `run` the Router, if the browser's URL isn't in the expected format, React won't actually render anything.